# How to parse XML where attribute values are not in quotes

Tags: c#, xml

My XML looks like this

```
<DIV id=MyID01 title="" style="HEIGHT: 100px; WIDTH: 200px;">
<OBJECT onmousedown=BodyMouseDown() id="Viewer" classid=CLSID:E9DAF39B-9CFF-451A-B777-856184C7D516></OBJECT></DIV>
```

Since MyID01 is not in quotes I get an error when I load it as XML.
Same with onmousedoun and classid attributes. 
How do I add Quotes to the attribute values programmatically ? I was thinking on the lines of regex, but wanted to know if I have another way.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a valid `Xml`.

Comment: This is html. Try to use any Html parser.

Comment: Is it only these three attributes (id, onmousedown, and classid) that have this problem?

Comment: Right, Its not a valid XML. It looks like HTML. HTML is not XML. HTML is based on SGML, and as such does not ensure that the markup is well-formed XML ,XML is a subset of SGML itself. You can only parse XHTML, i.e. XML compatible HTML, as XML. But of course that is not the case for most of the websites.

To work with HTML, you need to use a HTML parser.

Comment: @SvenGrosen Yes, only these three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to convert this html to quoted attribute-value syntax:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

to add the **HtmlAgilityPack** to you project and then you can do something like in this example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var html = new HtmlDocument();
            html.Load("C:\\test\\test.html");
            html.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Xml.XmlTextWriter xw = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(sw);
            html.Save("C:\\test\\test.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the result I get in test.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<div id="MyID01" title="" style="HEIGHT: 100px; WIDTH: 200px;">
  <object onmousedown="BodyMouseDown()" id="Viewer" classid="CLSID:E9DAF39B-9CFF-451A-B777-856184C7D516"></object>
</div>
```

Note that **HtmlAgilityPack** save function give a lot of different ways to get the xml from the parser.

Comment: This is works perfectly for me. Thanks for your time and effort @iiliev